# More modern image maps?

Tags: javascript, css, html

With all the recent advances in JavaScript/HTML5 it would be nice to think there would be a more modern way of implementing an image map. I know you can set a map property for the  tag but I don't think this supports nicely formatted tooltips on rollover (near the region). My requirement are really just tooltips, onClick/doubleClick actions on a region within an image.

Last questions on here about similar things I found were from 5 years ago.

Ideally I'd like to use pure js/html/css and not use JQuery plugins etc although I see there are a few available.

Comment: Interesting but is it on topic here in stackoverflow? Not sure. In any case, you can try to combine different plugins, there are a few plugins that may help you, like the jQuery responsive map plugin and the bootstrap's tooltips. I think that these, combined, can give you the desired result. http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html (<-- github: https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps) . Without any plugin I suspect you must start from scratch, which is probably not helpful.

Comment: Could you show us some code? And/or maybe create a fiddle of the map where you'd want those tool tips to appear?

Comment: Yes, previously I've used standard <img> with a map (which don't allow tooltips), I've also see plugins/frameworks which allow this. My question is - have things moved on to a point where we can do this in pure js/html5/css3?

Comment: SVG is the modern way in my opinion

Comment: You can embed the standard image inside the SVG and then add other elements as you wish though.

Comment: @Paulie_D - your comment made me think and I've created a SVG solution and added it to my answer - what do you think?

Comment: @briosheje Yes, this question is obviously on-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Responsive SVG solution or classic image map

After taking [Paulie_D's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998955/more-modern-image-maps/30999601#comment50027294_30998955) about SVG into account, I wrote an alternative using SVG to the classic image map. Both work fine, but the SVG version clearly wins when it comes to responsiveness. Both versions have a connection between the anchors and the respective tooltip using the `href`-attribute. Both solutions work with vanilla JavaScript, without an extra library.

---

### SVG version

**Advantages**

- responsive
- tooltips can be placed easily using JavaScript

**HTML**

```
<svg id="map" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <image width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/300"/>

    <a xlink:href="#t_1">
        <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
    </a>

    <a xlink:href="#t_2">
        <rect x="150" y="150" width="50" height="50" />
    </a>
</svg>

<div class="t" id="t_1">Tooltip 1</div>
<div class="t" id="t_2">Tooltip 2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

svg {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

svg rect {
    fill: white;
    opacity: 0.1;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

svg rect:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.t {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s linear;
}

.t.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript***

```
var map = document.getElementById('map');
var areas = map.getElementsByTagName('a');
var offset = { left: 30, top: 70 };

for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
    areas[i].onmouseover = function() {
        // get child element
        var c = this.firstElementChild;
        // get tooltip
        var t = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('xlink:href').substr(1));
        // set styles
        t.style.left = (map.offsetLeft + parseInt(c.getAttribute('x')) + offset.left) + 'px';
        t.style.top = (map.offsetTop + parseInt(c.getAttribute('y')) + offset.top) + 'px';
        // show it
        t.classList.toggle('active');
    }
    areas[i].onmouseout = function() {
        // get tooltip
        var t = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('xlink:href').substr(1));
        // hide it
        t.classList.toggle('active');
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- the positioning could be improved, it's just to show a direction

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/4dtbnbnd/)

---

### Classic image map version

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" usemap="#map">
<map id="map" name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="#t_1" alt="Tip 1" data-left="80px" data-top="80px" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,150,150" href="#t_2" alt="Tip 2" data-left="180px" data-top="180px" />
</map>

<div class="t" id="t_1">Tooltip 1</div>
<div class="t" id="t_2">Tooltip 2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.t {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s linear;
}

.t.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript***

```
var areas = document.getElementById('map').children;

for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
    areas[i].onmouseover = function() {
        var t = document.getElementById(this.hash.substr(1));
        t.style.left = this.dataset.left;
        t.style.top = this.dataset.top;
        t.classList.toggle('active');
    }
    areas[i].onmouseout = function() {
        var t = document.getElementById(this.hash.substr(1));
        t.classList.toggle('active');
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- attaching the position using the `data-*`-attributes, decouples the JavaScript (unfortunately [you can't use `offsetLeft/Top`](https://github.com/jquery/standards/issues/5) and determine the position based on the `area`-element) - you could however calculate it by using the `coords`-attribute
- the JavaScript code could be improved (for example store tooltips instead of re-query them all the time)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljdx8725/)

---

<sup>* In both examples the JavaScript could be improved, e.g. store tooltip elements in a variable instead of re-query them all the time.</sup>

Comment: This is great - I hadn't seen the dataset / data options for an element before so wouldn't have thought of creating the tooltips like that